# Password required while building a USB disk

Tags: boot, permissions

I was following the instructions given in STEP 8 http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Nevertheless, in STEP 8,
I got the message (after I introduced the my laptop-user PASSWORD):

```
sudo dd if=/Users/janjakobvivde/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.img.dmg of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m
dd: /dev/rdisk2: Permission denied
```

What I did wrong?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `cat` instead of `dd`; I believe it's faster anyway but it will take more than one command.

(this usually works with iso files so I think it will work with a dmg image)

Run these commands one-by-one:

```
sudo -s
cat /Users/janjakobvivde/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.img.dmg > /dev/rdisk2
exit
sudo -k
```

Also, an alternative to `sudo -s` is `sudo su`.

Comment: I was asked for a password..and finally denied:

Jean-Jacquess-MacBook-Pro:~ janjakobvivde$ sudo -s
Password:


bash-3.2# cat /Users/janjakobvivde/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.img.dmg > /dev/rdisk2
bash: /dev/rdisk2: Permission denied
bash-3.2#

Comment: @jeanjacquesvivde Three things: is the USB device write protected, is the device mounted, and has the device been formatted to vfat or fat32?

Comment: @jeanjacquesvivde another thing: have you previously used dd on the USB device before? If so, you will need to reformat the device or it will otherwise remain in write protected mode until you reformat it. That is one of the downsides of creating a boot device from a pendrive using dd or cat; for some reason the device goes into write protect mode afterwards. This can be a good thing but it doesn't allow the ability to have persistent storage across "live" sessions. If you are just wanting to install or test ubuntu out though, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @jeanjacquesvivde a lot of the commands are the same and I've never formatted a usb device on apple using the command line but on other nix based systems, you would use `sudo mkfs -t vfat -I /dev/sdX` replacing `/dev/sdX` with the actual USB device  just **remember to always be be careful when you are formatting anything**. Like the old saying goes "*measure twice, cut once*"

Comment: Thank you very much for all the comments and help. I will try to get bootable DVD.. I hope it will be more easy. Thank you. JJ